# front controller won't load css and js from setMedia on a prestashop 1.7 module

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I'm writing a prestashop module for prestashop 1.7.2.1.

I created a front controller for my module with the following code:

```
<?php

require_once (__DIR__.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'..'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'..'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'php'.
DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'TuxInDb.php');

class TuxInModCarTypeCarTypeProductsModuleFrontController extends ModuleFrontController {

    private $tuxDb;

    public function initContent(){
        parent::initContent();
        $productIds = [];
        $this->tuxDb = TuxInDb::getInstance();
        $companyName = Tools::getValue('company_name');
        $modelName = Tools::getValue('model_name');
        $year = Tools::getValue('year');
        $month = Tools::getValue('month');
        $carType = Tools::getValue('car_type');
        $carListCarTypeIds=$this->tuxDb->getCarListCarTypeIds($companyName,$modelName,$carType,$year,$month);
        $productIds = $this->tuxDb->getProductIdsByCarListCarTypeIds($carListCarTypeIds);
        $this->context->smarty->assign('product_ids',$productIds);
        $this->setTemplate('module:tuxinmodcartype/views/templates/front/cartypeproducts.tpl');
    }

    public function setMedia() {
        parent::setMedia();
        $this->registerStylesheet('module-tuxinmodcartype-cartypeproducts-style','modules/'.$this->module->name.'/css/cartypeproducts.css');
        $this->registerJavascript('module-tuxinmodcartype-cartypeproducts-js','modules/'.$this->module->name.'/js/cartypeproducts.js');
    }

}
```

as you can see in `setMedia()` function I load a css and js files.
I even debugged it in xdebug and I noticed that those lines of code actually get executed, but when I try to browse my front controller with the following url:

```
http://prestashop.dev:8080/index.php?company_name=BMW&model_name=SERIA+1&year=2011&month=1&car_type=5+%D7%93%D7%9C%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%AA+%28%D7%94%D7%90%D7%A6%D7%B3%D7%91%D7%A7%29&fc=module&module=tuxinmodcartype&controller=cartypeproducts&id_lang=1
```

and I check the network tab of my google chrome browser I noticed that the js and css file I required do not get loaded.

any ideas?

I see no javascript errors or php errors (I also have DEV enabled in prestashop).

Answer (score 0):

If an asset path is wrong then Prestashop won't even append it to the browser's `<head>` (or bottom depending on CCC settings) and won't throw out any errors.

Probably your path is incorrect, to get proper path use this:

```
$this->registerStylesheet('module-tuxinmodcartype-cartypeproducts-style', $this->module->getPathUri() . 'css/cartypeproducts.css');
$this->registerJavascript('module-tuxinmodcartype-cartypeproducts-js', $this->module->getPathUri() . 'js/cartypeproducts.js');
```

Comment: thank you. i'll use this from now on.. but it still provides the same results. same path as I used before that the files do not load

Comment: i'll try to debug to see where it fails

Comment: @ufk You can debug it [here](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/1.7.2.x/classes/assets/JavascriptManager.php#L57). Add before marked line `if ($id == 'module-tuxinmodcartype-cartypeproducts-js') die($this->getFullPath($relativePath));` This should show you if AssetManager is correctly parsing the link.

Comment: ok... i debugged and it does find the js and css files and provide the proper relative path. JavascriptManager.php's add function adds the file to the list properly. but still it doesn't load

Comment: ahmm.. I debugged and noticed that in FrontController php file getStylesheets() and getJavascript() get executed, return the proper values (even the main requirements of css and js of this module) but in the network tab of my google chrome I notice that nothing gets requested.

Answer (score 0):

**This works well with PrestaShop 1.7.x**

Add this inside your ModuleFrontController:

```
public function setMedia()
{
    parent::setMedia();
    $this->addCSS($this->module->getPathUri().'views/css/style.css');
}
```

I hope this helps!